# HTTP and HTTPS mixing broblem

Tags: apache, http, ubuntu, ssl, ubuntu-12.04

I have a dedicated server with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64bit). The server is for website hosting and it have Apache. I have some websites which use SSL. The server have therefore also the SSL mod installed. Websites which use SSL (port 443) works very well. Websites which use port 80 work normally, but when I put the prefix https on normal http website broblems start. Apache set other SSL site sertificate to this website and browser warn about it. Here is my normal website virtualhost file (port 80):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin contact@domain.com
        ServerName domain.com

        # Indexes + Directory Root.
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        DocumentRoot /home/www/domain/htdocs/

        # CGI Directory
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/www/domain/cgi-bin/
        <Location /cgi-bin>
                Options +ExecCGI
        </Location>


        # Logfiles
        ErrorLog  /home/www/domain/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /home/www/domain/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I remove the  SSL for all http pages? Is there some type of code which disable SSL on port 80 websites and redirect them to http website?